# PHP JavaScript 101. Separation of concerns

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, separation-of-concerns

**Context:**

I'm extremely novice in PHP & Laravel.

I've inherited an older application with quite a lot of interesting things that happen all over the code base... coupled with being new to PHP & Laravel... it all seems quite hairy at this stage. (Coming from working in Angular for about 4/5 years, I'm having to re-learn a lot)

**Scenario:**

Our app is mainly focused int the African space, and HAS to run on Opera-Mini. I've been told & read up online that opera mini & AJAX aren't friends at all. (This is also my first encounter with having this platform as a first class citizen)

I'd like to ask a few of PHP experts out there, about some of the general practices, and more specifically confirming/disproving my thoughts around:

- should I worry about this
- attempt to clean it up
- leave as is.

About 90% of the javascript in the app resided in `*.blade.php` files within `<script></script>` tags, with blade `{{ }}` bindings thrown in the mix.

```
@section('scripts')
    @parent
    @if(config('my.whatever.something.isEnabled'))
        <script>
            // seems fine
            var fooText = "{{ $foo }}"

            // IDE will complain but is still "fine"
            var barBoolean = {{ config('my.whatever.something.booleanFlag') }}
           
            if(barBoolean) {
               console.log(fooText);

               // this seems dirty to me (within the context of this script tag)
               <?php trigger_analytics_click_event('ga_analytics_something') ?>
            }
        </script>
    @endif
@stop
```

Usage:

```
@include('partials._foo',
[
   'foo' => true,
   'baz' => (config('partials.baz') - $baz->things->count())
])
```

**Questions:**

1. Is it common practice to mix these 2 paradigms to this extent in this fashion? Eg shouldn't JS reside in JS files. (I'm not saying dont use PHP & JS together... more like, how would one use them correctly?)

   - My immediate thoughts are shift more of the JS into their own
     <strike>correct</strike> files, thus enabling the browser to cache
     them, and then have more of a client side controller of sorts
   - There are obviously a lot of complexities in doing so as, the inline PHP cant live inside the JS file thus I'd need to make use of DI in some form..., and again thats a whole other story.
2. If the above is seen as ok. `PHP` -> inside -> `JS` -> inside -> `blade.php` -> inside  -> `<script>`

   Why does my IDE complain? Is there a config/setting that I'm missing to make this OK? (I know how ridiculous this sounds)

[image]

I've tried wrapping the above in text quotes, while it does resolve the red squiggle... it does mean that I need another level of parsing/decoding from text -> boolean/actual value.

3. I've seen another option of either binding to the DOM. Creating hidden fields, binding to them using `{{ }}`, then retrieving the field value using JS, but this also seems round about? (Is it)

Comment: PHPStorm right? I always use quotes to write PHP script inside script tag such as `minImageDimension: "{{domain_config('core.image') ? : 'false'}}"` however I don't get your question clearly, can you summarize your question up?

Comment: yeah - try and avoid mixing js and php, if you need data from php, assign it to a hidden span/input DOM element as data-* attributes and call using `.data()`

Comment: @RohanBüchner I can't comment because is too long, check my answer buddy. Anyway, this is not officially my answer ^^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing PHP and JS is not a good practice. But it's often inevitable in conventional PHP applications, as you need to somehow pass the data from PHP to Javascript.

One approach to make code look cleaner is to wrap all PHP variables in one JS variable and use it in JS code. Consider the example:

Before:

```
<script>
  // A lot of PHP inline variables. PHP & JS tightly coupled.
  func1("{{ $var1 }}");

  func2("{{ $var2 }}");

  if ("{{ $var3 }}") {
   func3();
  }
</script>
```

After:

```
<script>
  // PHP code in a single place
  var options = {
    one: "{{ $var1 }}",
    two: "{{ $var2 }}",
    three: "{{ $var3 }}"
  }; 

  // JS code without PHP-inlines 
  func1(options.one);
  func2(options.two);        
  if (options.three) {
   func3();
  }      
</script>
```

Using this approach, JS code becomes much less coupled to PHP and you can even put it in a separate .js file and call it with `options` variable as a function argument:

**someFunc.js**

```
// JS code without PHP-inlines 
function someFunc(options) {
  func1(options.one);
  func2(options.two);        
  if (options.three) {
   func3();
  }
}
```

**view.blade.php**:

```
<script>
  // PHP code in single place
  var options = {
    one: "{{ $var1 }}",
    two: "{{ $var2 }}",
    three: "{{ $var3 }}"
  }; 

  someFunc(options);      
</script>
```

---

After all, it's a matter of readability and maintainability of the code that you should worry about. If some complex piece of JS code is duplicated in many templates or mixed with PHP so that it's hard to read, it's definitely worth refactoring. But if the code snippets are simple (like in your example) I wouldn't bother refactoring it until later

Comment: @RohanBüchner all PHP variables must be converted to JSON when embedded in JS code. In plain PHP it's done with `json_encode()`. Maybe blade has some nice syntax, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I've just done a quick test, so I write a simple script base on your question

```
<?php
    $config = true;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isHappen = "{{($config) ?:false}}";
    //convert to boolean
    isHappen = (isHappen === "1");
    if(isHappen)
    {
        alert('ok');
    } else {
        alert('not ok');
    }
</script>
```

Then view this source when I run it on browser

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isHappen = "1";
    //convert to boolean
    isHappen = (isHappen === "1");
    if(isHappen)
    {
        alert('ok');
    } else {
        alert('not ok');
    }
</script>
```

Boolean just a number `0` and `1`, in this case, boolean is automatically converted by browser to number if you put in quotes so you can see `var isHappen = "1";` and in this case you can't compare like `>` `<` but it still fine if you just want to check if is `true` or `false`.

However, in my opinion, you should avoid using PHP variable inside javascript, just try to find better solution.

Hope this help,

Comment: The problem is, if `isHappen` where set to `"0"` for false. It would also assert to `true`... thus I'd need to parse to boolean first... (thank you anyway, this does confirm my suspicion that I don't have many other options in this regard anyway)

Comment: @RohanBüchner is not assert to `true` if you use quotes I've been testing recently, still work fine. `//$config = false; result "not ok"` or if you just want to parse to boolean, it is simple `isHappen = (isHappen === '1');`

Comment: I think you have many options to solve your problem, just post your part of codes where you stuck on, you will get help.